# Count down timer for Arduino sketch

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-ide

I [wrote an Arduino sketch](https://ghostbin.com/paste/hnngh) a little while ago, and I am trying to add functionality to the sketch.  Basically I want a count down timer that closes a solenoid cut off valve after 30 seconds has passed.

Comment: This will probably get closed as too broad. You want to close the solenoid valve 30 seconds after what? We need more info here.

Comment: after 30 seconds from when it is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using timers and interrupts, but some more informations is needed (which board, which processor).

**Note:** `F_CPU` is already defined if you are using arduino libraries (`#define F_CPU 20000000U`)

**Note 2:** You may want to use another timer than TIMER0 since it is use to track time on arduino

```
#define GMilliSecondPeriod F_CPU / 1000

unsigned int gNextOCR = 0;
volatile unsigned long gMillis = 0;
bool valveOpened = false;

// This interruption will be called every 1ms
ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect)
{
  if(valve_open){
    gMillis++;
    if(gMillis >= 30000){
      close_valve();
      gMillis = 0;
    }
  }  

  gNextOCR += GMilliSecondPeriod;
  OCR2A = gNextOCR >> 8; // smart way to handle millis, they will always be average of what they should be
}

// Just call this function within your setup
void setupTime(){
  TCCR2B |= _BV(CS02);
  TIMSK2 |= _BV(OCIE0A);

  sei(); // enable interupts
}
```

Comment: This code should be ok on Arduino UNO, just make sure to use another timer than timer1, I updated the code with timer2.

Comment: (I wanted to say other than timer0, because timer0 is used by millis and delay function on Arduino)

Comment: This is the correct line for 30 seconds BTW, `if(gMillis >= 30000)`

Comment: Little tip/note/info, non related to your question, with this code you can theoretically replace the Arduino millis() method, this one is much more accurate, because it doesn't introduce some second shift every day. The OCR2A = gNextOCR >> 8, modify the interrupt interval each time, which cause every millisecond to be the average of what they should be. Arduino just count lineary and then increase 2ms instead of 1ms some times.